# How arithmetic operators works for infinity value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, ecmascript-6, operators

### Why Arithmetic operators works differently for infinity value in JavaScript?

```js
console.log(1.7976931348623157E+10308 + 1.7976931348623157E+10308)//Infinity
console.log(1.7976931348623157E+10308 * 1.7976931348623157E+10308)//Infinity
console.log(1.7976931348623157E+10308 - 1.7976931348623157E+10308)/NaN
console.log(1.7976931348623157E+10308 / 1.7976931348623157E+10308)/NaN
```

Actually `1.7976931348623157E+10308` is a `Infinity` value. You can check below how arithmetic operators returning results for Infinity value.

```js
console.log(Infinity + Infinity)//Infinity
console.log(Infinity * Infinity)//Infinity
console.log(Infinity - Infinity)/NaN
console.log(Infinity / Infinity)/NaN
```

So my question's are..

> - Why `+` and `*` operator returning `Infinity` while doing arithmetic operation in between  `Infinity` Value?
> - Why `-` and `/` operator returning `NaN` while doing arithmetic operation in between  `Infinity` Value?

Comment: Because it makes sense mathematically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the spec explicitly says it should do that.

[+](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-applying-the-additive-operators-to-numbers):

> The sum of two infinities of the same sign is the infinity of that sign.

[*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-applying-the-mul-operator):

> Multiplication of an infinity by an infinity results in an infinity. The sign is determined by the rule already stated above.

[-](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-applying-the-additive-operators-to-numbers):

> The sum of two infinities of opposite sign is NaN.

[/](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-applying-the-div-operator):

> Division of an infinity by an infinity results in NaN.